# Matching a specific piece of text in a title using Beuatiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml, python-webbrowser

Basically, I want to find all links that contain certain key terms.  In my case, the titles of these links that I want come in this form: abc... (common text), dce... (common text), ...  I want to take all of the links containing "(common text)" and put them in the list.  I got the code working and I understand how to find all links.  However, I converted the links to strings to find the "(common text)".  I know that this isn't good practice and I am not sure how to use Beautiful Soup to find this common element without converting to a string.  The issue here is that the titles I am searching for are not all the same.  Here's what I have so far:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import requests
 import webbrowser

 url = 'website.com'
 http = requests.get(url)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(http.content, "lxml")

 links = soup.find_all('a', limit=4000)
 links_length = len(links)

 string_links = []
 targetlist = []
 
 for a in range(links_length):
       string_links.append(str(links[a]))  
       if '(common text)' in string_links[a]:
             targetlist.append(string_links[a])
```

NOTE: I am looking for the simplest method using Beautiful Soup to accomplish this.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `find_all` supports regex `soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("EXPRESSION"))` . All you need to do is create a regular expression which matches your "common element"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the actual website and actual output you want, it's very difficult to say what you want but this is a "cleaner" solution using list comprehension.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import webbrowser

url = 'website.com'
http = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(http.content, "lxml")

links = soup.find_all('a', limit=4000)

targetlist = [str(link) for link in links if "(common text)" in str(link)]
```